# Need guidance with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, web-hosting

I am learning php, and for a project I am trying to use phpmailer. I have a website hosted and am trying to send a mail via a contact form but it doesn't seem to work.

```html
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Load Composer's autoloader
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'example.net';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'myusername.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
        $mail->addAddress('test@mail.com', 'John Doe');     // Add a recipient
        //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
        //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
        //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
        //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

        //Attachments
        //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
        //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Mail from Website';
        $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'Testing mail';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
header("Location: index.php");
```

I have changed some info, especially in SMTP for security reasons.

---

So I did some changes and I got this as the output

```html
2018-10-10 06:42:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-cp-ht-9.webhostbox.net ESMTP Exim 4.91 #1 Wed, 10 Oct 2018 06:42:52 +0000 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.hostname.com
2018-10-10 06:42:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-cp-ht-9.webhostbox.net Hello www.hostname.com [162.241.148.100]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2018-10-10 06:42:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.christopherdias.info
2018-10-10 06:42:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-cp-ht-9.webhostbox.net Hello www.hostname.com [162.241.148.100]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2018-10-10 06:42:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2018-10-10 06:42:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2018-10-10 06:42:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<test@mail.com>
2018-10-10 06:42:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<me@hostname.com>
2018-10-10 06:42:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2018-10-10 06:42:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2018 06:42:52 +0000
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Jane Doe <me@hostname.com>
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: John <test@mail.com>
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Mail from Website
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <XHLR5jcAlBhaDRm37Jtfwnnz5njYjR0UViZapBxdG4Y@www.hostname.com>
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.0.5 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_XHLR5jcAlBhaDRm37Jtfwnnz5njYjR0UViZapBxdG4Y"
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_XHLR5jcAlBhaDRm37Jtfwnnz5njYjR0UViZapBxdG4Y
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: Testing mail
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_XHLR5jcAlBhaDRm37Jtfwnnz5njYjR0UViZapBxdG4Y
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_XHLR5jcAlBhaDRm37Jtfwnnz5njYjR0UViZapBxdG4Y--
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2018-10-10 06:42:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Message denied for spoofing attempt via SMTP Auth (From address: John <test@mail.com> IP: 162.241.148.100 AuthenticatedID: me@hostname.com Account owner: myname)
2018-10-10 06:42:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-10-10 06:42:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 cp-ht-9.webhostbox.net closing connection
Message has been sent
```

Mail still not sending though.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: And your question is what? "it doesn't seem to work" is a bit lame...

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: You need to refer to your hosting provider or email provider to get the appropriate host/port information.

Comment: change host and port according to your email hosting provider.

Comment: @herondale. I do not get any errors apart from  not receiving an email after submitting the form. and I have used the SMTP information provided by the hosting provider. I just changed it here for security reasons.

Comment: This code should throw `headers already sent`-messages since you're echoing text before you redirect the user. Remove the redirect in the end and check what you see on the screen. You should get a bunch of information since you're having `SMTPDebug = 2`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I tried what you asked me to do. I just get a blank page without any errors.

Comment: Make sure that it enters the if-statement at all. Add a `die('foo');` as the first line inside the if-statement. If you don't see that, then `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` doesn't evaluate as true. You should then add your form to the question.

Comment: What about this line:  SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Message denied for spoofing attempt via SMTP Auth (From address: John <test@mail.com> IP: 162.241.148.100 AuthenticatedID: me@hostname.com Account owner: myname). It looks like you are trying to send the mail with the wrong user.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`, but `Port = 465`. This won't work, none of the examples do it, and the docs tell you that this combination will not work. Your ISP would not have told you to do this either. With this combination you will get no debug output because it will not succeed in opening a connection at all, and thus there is no SMTP traffic to debug.

Change it to `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` *or* (not *and*) `Port = 587`.

Comment: I made some changes and posted the update in the edit.